# Disabling Location on Android app close

Tags: android, location, bluetooth-lowenergy

On the Andorid app I'm working on, there is the need to scan for BLE devices, and a requesite to do so is to enable the Location. I have done it following the methods described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html), by Google.

Since I only need to enable the location, but not actually get any data from it, instead of using

```
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}
```

I only use

```
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER);
}
```

This is working fine.

My question is how do I ***disable*** the location once the user leaves the app.

Comment: What did mean saying 'disable' ? Disabling the location actually means preventing to receive location for device (for all applications). So if you wishing to stop receive location for your app, then the way is `removeLocationUpdates`

Comment: My app does not receive location updates, I never run `requestLocationUpdates`. I just need Location to be enabled, not necessarily reporting data.

What I want is to turn location off, to the state it was before calling `checkLocationSettings`.